# Can I edit an Apk for removing Ads even getting updates?

Tags: google-play-store, apk, android-10, editing

There are various sources for downloading an apk.

After installing an apk, Play Store detects the app. And it shows updates, if any update is available.

After updating the app, the app starts ads.

Can I edit the apk such a way so that even after updating the app from Play Store, it shouldn’t start ads?

If yes, please let me know and elaborate steps.

I’ll be thankful for giving your time.

With Regards

FewL

Comment: Editing an APK destroys the signature and you have resign using a different key. Afterwards you can't install updates from Play Store.

Comment: Alternatives are using an [Ad-Blocker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_adblocker) – or get your apps from [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) whenever possible. Both approaches can be combined, of course.